# GDB: Passing EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal to program

Tags: iphone, debugging, gdb, signals, exc-bad-access

Note: This question stems from another question I asked about iPhone launching: [Launch installed app on tethered iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404410/launch-installed-app-on-tethered-iphone)

I have a situation where I need to catch all signals, particularly EXC_BAD_ACCESS for use in a crash handler. When the GDB is attached to the process it handles the signal and breaks rather than letting the program take care of it.

GDB has the command `handle all noprint pass nostop` which is supposed to pass all signals on to the program and not break. This works for all signals that I've tried except  EXC_BAD_ACCESS, even though its listed in its signal list.

Now the i386 Darwin 6.3.5 version of GDB also has the command `dont-handle-bad-access 1`. If I switch this on and trigger the signal, GDB successfully passes on the signal which turns into a SIGBUS in the program.

Now for the crux of my problem. I'm debugging remotely on a connected iPhone. The GDB version which is used is the ARMV7 6.3.5 version, which unfortunately does not have the `dont-handle-bad-access` command. If I leave the `handle all noprint pass nostop` command on and trigger a crash the debugger hangs, and if I leave it default the debugger catches the signal and my signal handler is never entered.

Is there a way to properly get this version of GDB to pass along the EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal, or is there a way to trigger an action on any kind of crash or break (in which case I can signal a SIGBUS or at least quit the program).

Comment: I don't know any Apple stuff, but I'm pretty good with gdb and nobody else is answering so I'll take a shot if you help me out by posting a copy of everything that gdb prints when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround, use setting handle all print pass nostop and monitor the error stream, if you see the line like `Program received signal ...`, kill the process gdb-arm-apple-darwin