# Applescript to automate building and running on iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, applescript

I can't find an example of an Applescript that build and launches the app on a iOS device. There are several examples to "build" the app, but none that launch it on the device. Basically, what I want to do is the equivalent of clicking the run button in XCode, with a specific device selected on the drop-down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fruitstrap](https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap) lets you install and start an application on an attached device from the command line. I'm not an AppleScript guy but I suspect that modifying your AppleScript to use this utility would not be too challenging.

Comment: Yep, I've tried that, but the problem is that it doesn't launch the app. It only installs it on the device.

Comment: You can use the `-d` option to start it, albeit, in the debugger.

Comment: if that's not what you want you need to use a bootstrap program and a custom URL See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404410/launch-installed-app-on-tethered-iphone